# WMI win32_product installState property

Tags: wmi, system-center

Doing a wmi query on a few systems on my network returns installState=1 for a given software. However, it doesnt appear in add remove programs or HKLM\software\microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\uninstall or even the same key under wow6432node
How do I go about removing it?

Comment: Was it already uninstalled? Not all software enters a key under uninstall - check the local software folder for an uninstall executable.

Comment: Wasn't uninstalled. This is what happened- Task sequence failed to install the software due to wrongly created package settings and installer program. Now it shows installState=1. Nothing relevant to it on local filesystem either.

Comment: Check these 2 reg paths: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\

Comment: nothing in both reg paths, however following cmdlet- get-wmiobject -class win32_product -computername . | select-object -property name,identifyingnumber,installstate | where-object {$_.name -match "xyz app*"} | format-list shows installState=1 in the output

Comment: Are you sure the program isn't listed in Add Remove Programs? That's the wmi class for it

Comment: Definitely not listed, checked on 3 systems. This is verified by the fact, installLocaiton and installDate properties are blank

Answer (score 0):

Return the object in WMI from Win32_Product and use its Uninstall method:

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "xyz app"}
$app.Uninstall()
```

Comment: That seems to work. The application in question doesn't show installstaus=1 anymore